# WCF - public interface - how to secure the interface?

Tags: wcf

I have an new system which has two main WFC interfaces:

1. a server-to-server interface, which is protected by our router/firewall (PFSense, all good)
2. a public interface, which our downloaded apps use to interface with our server.

I am trying to determine the best way with the public interface (option 2) to secure the connection.
I can't limit by Authentication.  I just want to make sure that only our app is using the interface.
Also, I don't think I can use a cert.

Should I just code in some type of token to the methods?  Or something easier?

Thanks in advance for the ideas!

Comment: only some kind of authenication will protect that.

Comment: but it is public.  our current solution is to have a parameter which encodes our end user's ID, that we then decode, and only proceeed if ok.  Is that the best solution?  Ok if yes, but that is my question!

Comment: you should have a username and password then.

Comment: @DanielA.White: ok, but a .NET WinForms or WPF app could be reverse engineered?  Am I missing something?   Is your solution to have a app.config or similar authentication mechanism?  (we considered that)

Comment: yes it could. a cert would be the best way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Certificates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648360.aspx). Here is a good example

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/wcf_certificates.aspx

Comment: is it realistic to use certs from an end user who downloads a commercial (non-financial or critical) app?  Our goal is for basic security (keep others from messing with our interface), but it isn't mission critical.